# XCODE / IOS - Share via UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, swift, share, whatsapp, uidocumentinteractioncontroller

I havn't succeeded to share anything via the "UIDocumentInteractionController", as I went through almost all the tutorials and help online I wish to find a solution:

This is the code i use:

```
    let fileName = "banner_1"
    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "jpg")!
    let urlData = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
    let nsData = NSData(contentsOf: urlData)

    let newFileName = "banner_1.jpg"
    let newFilePath = "\(NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0])/\(newFileName)"
    nsData?.write(toFile: newFilePath, atomically: true)
    let newUrlData = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: newFilePath)

    documentController?.url = urlData // or newUrlData
    documentController?.uti = "net.whatsapp.image"
    documentController?.presentOpenInMenu(from: CGRect.zero, in: self.view, animated: true)
```

Everytime I press one tile of the sharing menu for whatsapp or messenger, nothing happen and i have this error log:

> 2018-02-02 19:56:31.293849-0300 myapp[748:116227] [core] SLComposeViewController initWithExtension:  {id = net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension} requestedServiceType: (null)
>
> 2018-02-02 19:56:31.296021-0300 myapp[748:116227] [core] SLComposeViewController addExtensionItem:  - userInfo: {
>       NSExtensionItemAttachmentsKey =     (
>           " {types = (\n    \"public.jpeg\",\n    \"public.file-url\"\n)}"
>       );
>   }
>
> 2018-02-02 19:56:31.883007-0300 myapp[748:116227] [core] viewWillAppear
>
> 2018-02-02 19:56:31.883240-0300 myapp[748:116227] [core] SLComposeViewController including 1 explicit NSExtensionItems
>
> 2018-02-02 19:56:31.883311-0300 myapp[748:116227] [core] SLComposeViewController about to instantiate remote view controller with array of 1 NSExtensionItems
>
> 2018-02-02 19:56:31.886583-0300 myapp[748:116227] [core] viewDidAppear
>
> 2018-02-02 19:56:31.989725-0300 myapp[748:116362] [ops] Hub connection error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension}
>
> 2018-02-02 19:56:31.991895-0300 myapp[748:116227] [core] SLComposeViewController finished instantiate remote view controller (null) error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension} extension request identifier (null)
>
> 2018-02-02 19:56:31.992325-0300 myapp[748:116227] [core] HOST: Failed to load remote view controller with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension}
>
> 2018-02-02 19:56:31.992433-0300 myapp[748:116227] [core] Sheet not being presented, calling premature completion
>
> 2018-02-02 19:56:31.992479-0300 myapp[748:116227] [core] SLComposeViewController completeWithResult: 0
>
> 2018-02-02 19:56:31.995770-0300 myapp[748:116227] [core] SLComposeViewController skipping explicit dismiss because isBeingDismissed is already 1
>   g
>
> 2018-02-02 19:56:32.001500-0300 myapp[748:116227] [core] SLComposeViewController dealloc

I did added "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes" with "whatsapp" in the plist file.

I tried with the UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate to find if there is any strange event but didn't helped a lot.

If you have any adea ?!
Thanks, Antoine.

Comment: Are you running on a real iOS device with WhatsApp installed?

Comment: Yes on my iphone 6 with last os, whatsapp and messenger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working code through that you can share your image to whatsapp, All you need to do is just add **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes** **whatsapp** into your plist file for WhatsApp sharing enable.

**Swift 4**

```
func shareOnWhatsUp() {

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "whatsapp://app")!) {
        var documentInteractionController: UIDocumentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController.init()
        let iconImage = UIImage(named: "IMG_1.jpg")
        let pathURL =   URL.init(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/whatsAppTmp.wai")

        do {
            try UIImageJPEGRepresentation(iconImage!, 1.0)?.write(to: pathURL)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        documentInteractionController!.url = pathURL
        documentInteractionController!.uti = "net.whatsapp.image"
        documentInteractionController!.delegate = self
        documentInteractionController!.presentOpenInMenu(from: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0), in: self.view, animated: true)
    }
    else {
        print("whatsup not installed")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is does open the share menu first, then the whatsapp menu if i click on whatsapp. One thing i've not figured out yet (from the whatsapp documentation: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/iphone/23559013/), is how to open whatsapp directly with the exclusive extention (.wai, .waa, .wam)

Comment: for the record, the "this item cannot be shared" error was fixed by creating a class with "UIDocumentInteractionController" & "UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate", then instanciate it in my root controller. and setting the delegate to self in the init of that new class.

Comment: Dear, As per your question definition i provided you working solution to share image with the whaapp, If you still facing any error just share me your source i can check it and fix it.

Comment: Thanks, the problem I had here is fixed, the sharing works. The next problem I have is about the whatsapp API. I asked the question there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48599394/xcode-ios-how-to-use-exclusive-extension-to-immediately-present-whatsapp-w. I couldn't find anyone online that sucessfully made it works, or talking about laking it work. I guess the problem is not about the code.